# unity launcher doesn't respond to mouse at the left side when the applications are fullscreen

Tags: unity, 11.10, launcher

I,ve just installed 11.10 and I have this problem that sometimes launcher doesn't respond to mouse and it does not reveal. when I do `unity --replace` in terminal nothing happens, it just set the DISPLAY initial variable to :0 and then unity is gone. I should restart lightdm after to restore the unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known bug. I haven't experienced it in Unity 2D, though, so if it bothers you, you can switch to Unity 2D for a while until it gets fixed. Unity 2D is nice as well. You can try it by clicking the button next to the password field before you log in.

It's a workaround, but there's little else to do for now. Remember to install upgrades often.

Comment: Please reference the bug!